# How to insert GROUP_CONCAT into query of products?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 related tables in mysql 8 :

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `status` enum('D','P','A','I') COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'D' COMMENT ' D => Draft, P=>Pending Review, A=>Active, I=>Inactive',
  `sale_price` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
...


CREATE TABLE `discount_product` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `discount_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL,
...  
  

CREATE TABLE `discounts` (
  `id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `min_qty` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `max_qty` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `percent` decimal(7,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `description` mediumtext COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL, 
...
```

I need to show products with related discounts in 2 column;

I have 2 working requests. 1st with 'discount_info content' placeholder:

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.sale_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT('discount_info content') AS discount_info

    FROM products WHERE has_discount_price = 1 AND id = 13
    GROUP BY products.id, products.title, products.sale_price
```

and second discounts by product id :

```
SELECT  CONCAT(discounts.name, ': ', discounts.min_qty, ': ', discounts.max_qty, ': ', discounts.percent)
  FROM discounts, discount_product WHERE discount_product.discount_id = discounts.id AND discount_product.product_id = 13
```

Both requests works ok.

But when I insert 2nd request inside of 'discount_info content' placeholder in 1st request using GROUP_CONCAT :

```
SELECT products.id, products.title, products.sale_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(SELECT  CONCAT(discounts.name, ': ', discounts.min_qty, ': ', discounts.max_qty, ': ', discounts.percent)
  FROM discounts, discount_product WHERE discount_product.discount_id = discounts.id AND discount_product.product_id = 13) AS discount_info


    FROM products WHERE has_discount_price = 1 AND id = 13
GROUP BY products.id, products.title, products.sale_price
```

I got error :

```
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM discounts, discount_product WHERE discount_product.discount_id = discounts.' at line 3
```

If I removed SELECT from inside of GROUP_CONCAT, but got the same error.

Why I got the error and how to fix it ?
Looks like I misundertsnd how GROUP_CONCAT works...

Comment: You are not showing the tables' primary keys, but it is rather obvious from the name that `id` should be the `products` primary key, as a product table should contain one row per product and a column called `id` should uniquely identify a row in a table. Otherwise that would be a horribly naming. But then, if the `id` is the primray key,, then why `GROUP BY id`? Your first query would be equal to a mere `SELECT products.id, products.title, products.sale_price, 'discount_info content' AS discount_info FROM products WHERE has_discount_price = 1 AND id = 13`.

Comment: As to the second query: `FROM discounts, discount_product` is an an ancient join syntax from the 1980s. Since SQL standard of 1992 we are using explicit joins instead, which was long before MySQL ever existed. I hope nobody *taught* you this syntax and you just happened to see it in some old book or so. Use explicit joins instead, ie `[INNER] JOIN` or `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` - whichever is appropriate.

Comment: As to the data model: What is `products.has_discount_price` good for? I would assume that a product that has an entry in `discount_product` has a discount and a product that has no such entry hasn't. Isn't that so?

Comment: Thanks for your hints! has_discount_price => discount_price_allowed and rows into discount_product can be added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want as the base of the query is a 2 way join between the `discount_product` junction table and the `products` and `discounts` tables.  Then, aggregate by product and use similar `GROUP_CONCAT()` logic.

```sql
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.title,
    p.sale_price,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(d.name, ': ', d.min_qty, ': ', d.max_qty, ': ', d.percent)) AS discount_info
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN discount_product dp
    ON dp.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN discounts d
    ON d.id = dp.discount_id
WHERE p.has_discount_price = 1 AND p.id = 13
GROUP BY p.id, p.title, p.sale_price;
```